# Node.js ibm_db installation error on CentOS

Tags: node.js, centos, db2

I'm making a simple app with angular and nodeJS, and need to connect to DB2 to access some procedures. The nodeJS server is installed in a Centos 6.5 server machine, but when I tried to install ibm_db using npm it showed some kind of error, started with

```
{ [Error: Command failed: In file included from ../src/odbc.h:23,
                 from ../src/odbc.cpp:25:
```

and ended with some kind of GYP error.

```
> gyp ERR! build error
> gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
> gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:267:23)
> gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
> gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:820:12)
> gyp ERR! System Linux 2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64
> gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "build" "--IBM_DB_HOME=/var/www/html/m-siam/trunk/server/node_modules/ibm_db/installer/clidrive
> gyp ERR! cwd /var/www/html/m-siam/trunk/server/node_modules/ibm_db
> gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.36
> gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.10.6
```

> gyp ERR! not ok

And when I tried to run the nodeJS server, it showed 'could not load the bindings file' error.

How do I install this module properly? I'm using nodeJS 0.10.36 and installing both ibm_db version 0.0.8 (the one coming from package.json) and version 0.0.10 result in the same error.

Comment: That line 23 in odbc.h points to "nan.h" which is used for native abstractions. Not sure if you manually need to pull that in. https://www.npmjs.com/package/nan

Comment: @HenrikLoeser I manually installed nan (npm install nan) but nothing changed, still the same error.

Comment: Do you have DB2 installed locally? I am asking because of whether you have installed the DB2 development libraries.

Comment: The ibm_db module automatically installed the DB2 ODBC CLI driver. Is it not that one? I can connect to database with PHP though (in the same server machine where I installed nodeJS), using db2_connect().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow, my colleague was able to install ibm_db module on another nodeJS directory. Maybe my app's directory dress is too long, I don't know, but I just copied the module from my colleague's directory to my own, and it now works perfectly.